# Python - Find variables that have a particular value

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have 5 variables and they take either a 1 or 0. I am trying to find which among those 5 variables are set to 1.

For example:

```
var_1 = 1 
var_2 = 1
var_3 = 0
var_4 = 1
var_5 = 0
```

I am expecting to get `var_1`, `var_2` and `var_4` as they are equal to 1.

Comment: You could use a list, then loop through the list

Comment: Most certainly you don't want have variable like this, but use proper data structure

Comment: You use proper data structure her. use list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    exec(f"if var_{i} == 1: print('var_{i}')")
```

This prints:

```
var_1
var_2
var_4
```

---

Or as chester suggested, use:

```
[i for i,v in globals().items() if v==1]
```

or the `locals()` (may raise Runtime error if you loop through it):

```
[i for i,v in locals().items() if v == 1]
```

Comment: You can use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#globals) to get global variables names try this `[i for i,v in globals().items() if v==1]`---->output is `['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_4']`. for local variables use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese I have added link to the documentation of `globals()` and `locals()` in the previous comment.

Comment: @Ch3steR is usage of exec() recommended to be avoided?

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Most programmers try to not use `exec` and `eval`. It's there last resort. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672791/how-to-safely-use-exec-in-python)

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese This [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/191628) provided by Martijn Pieters explains well

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese TBH I wouldn't use `globals()` or `locals()`. It's better to use a suitable data structure here something like a list or a dictionary ;)