# Python executing trusted but unreliable scripts

Tags: python

I want to be able to execute a list of developmental scripts.  Something like this:

```
def scriptRunner(scripts):
    for script in scripts
        import script
        result = script.run()
        # log result
```

This is a similar question to [Python, safe, sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688708/python-safe-sandbox), except that the scripts I intend to run will not be malicious.  They are development scripts created by other engineers.  They may crash, raise exceptions, get stuck in infinite loops -- these sorts of things -- but they won't try to execute rm -rf.

Is there a framework I can put around the script runner so that these conditions are handled and it just logs it and moves on to the next script?

Comment: What if they accidentally execute `rm -Rf /`?

Comment: Our engineers are not perfect, but neither are they incompetent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__import__](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

```
for script in scripts:
    __import__(script,  globals(), locals(), ['run'], -1)
    result = run()
    # log result
```